# Creating A Toolbar Info Button in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, button, xcode4.5, toolbar

I know how to create a toolbar button programmatically using `UIButton:buttonWithType:` and `UIBarButtonItem:initWithCustomView:` and supplying `UIButton:buttonWithType` the argument `UIButtonTypeInfoLight`.

What I'd really like to do is drag a system button onto a generic barbuttonitem to get an info button. In Interface Builder. Is this something one can do or should I just man up and write the code?

Comment: i.e. you just want to have a custom barButtonItem?

Comment: No, you can't do that. Man up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
let     infoButton        = UIButton.init( type: .infoLight )
let     infoBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init( image:  infoButton.image( for: .normal ),
                                                  style: .plain,
                                                  target: self,
                                                  action: #selector( infoBarButtonItemTouched ) )
```